# program can't move past a write method

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
with open('exr.txt','r+') as exr:
    while True:
        exr.write((input('enter your name ')+'\n'))
        b=exr.readlines()
        if 'q' in b:
            break
    print('names entered:')
    for c in b:
        print('-',c)
```

It never gets past the write() method and keeps prompting me for names even after entering 'q',
any help is appreciated

Comment: `.readlines()` returns a list, `'q' != ['q']`

Comment: Instead of reading the entire file after each input, why not just `name = input(...); if name == `q`: break else exr.write(name)`?

Comment: @tobias_k I know I can do that, I'm just wandering why it doesn't work in this case specifically

Comment: BTW, what exactly is it you want to achieve in the first place? Do you want to reuse the `exr.txt` file over multiple sessions, keeping appending names to it? If so, also note that the first `write`, before the `readlines`, will overwrite the content at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @tobias_k it's just an exercise from a book I'm reading, it asks you to use a while loop that prompts users for their names and then to save those names in a file, then it tells you to check that all names that were provided are actually stored in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three problems with your approach:

1. it seems like `exr.readlines()` does not work as you expected here, with `r+`, so a `"q"` entered in the current "session" is not read
2. in contrast to that, a `"q"` entered in a *previous* session *is* read, as they remain in the names file, i.e. the loop breaks immediately in any later execution
3. you are testing whether `"q"` is in `b`, but you append a `\n` to each input, and `readlines` includes those line-end characters, so `b` can only ever contain `"q\n"`

It seems like both reading and writing are using the same position in the file. You can get the position with `exr.tell()` and set it with `exr.seek(x)`. This way, you can see that:

- at the beginning of the loop, `exr.tell()`, i.e. the position is at `0`, meaning your first `write` will overwrite whatever data is at the beginning of the file
- after `write`, the position is at `k+1` for a name with `k` letters and the additional `\n`
- now `readlines` reads all data from *that position* (i.e. *after* the name you just entered) up to the end of the file
- now, the file position is at the end, and all subsequent `write` calls will append names to the end of the file, advancing the file position further to the new end, and `readlines` will read nothing, as the pointer is already at the end of the file

You *could* use `exr.seek(0)` to reset the position in the file to the beginning (or any other position before the last line), but while this (together with 3.) fixes the immediate problem, you still should not do it.

Instead, just store the input in a variable and check the value of that variable before adding it to the file or breaking from the loop.

```
with open('exr.txt', 'a') as exr:
    while True:
        name = input('enter your name ')
        if name == "q":
            break
        else:
            exr.write(name + '\n')
```

Comment: I added the \n because the write method keeps on writing in the same line and I want every name to be in a separate line, as the readlines method packs a list with every separate line, it is clear why I did this

Comment: @ashenone Yes, adding the `\n` is definitely the right thing here, I mainly wanted to point out that those are included in the strings returned by `readlines`

Comment: changing `if 'q' in b:` to `if 'q\n' in b:` doesn't fix the problem so it's defiantly something weird in the write method as changing `b=exr.readlines()
        if 'q' in b:
            break` to `print('foobar')` doesn't do anything as the program keeps on prompting me for a new name every time I provide one and doesn't seem to advance past that point, any way thanks for helping (:

Comment: @ashenone As I said, there are several problems, and just fixing one does not fix it all. Using `seek` to reset the read position before `readlines` _and_ checking for `"\n"` worked for me, though. But again, you should _not_ use this in practice.

Answer (score 0):

the .readlines() method returns a list and not a string
so when youre looking for q in a list of names ["jasper, "qar"] python sorta thinks this:
is the element "q" in this list? is "q" equal to "jasper" or "qar"? nope.
so you have to iterate through each element in b to go through each letter in each name in the list.

i would do something like this:

```
with open('exr.txt','r+') as exr:
while True:
    exr.write((input('enter your name ')+'\n'))
    b=exr.readlines()
    for name in b:
       for letter in name: 
           if 'q' in b:
              break
print('names entered:')
for c in b:
    print('-',c)
```

hope this is the answer youre looking for :)

Comment: Pretty sure OP does not want to break on any name with `q` but when the user enters a "q" as in "quit".

Comment: Also, the inner `for` loop is redundant; just `if 'q' in name` would work, too.

Comment: my bad i guess i didnt understand what he's tryna do haha this was hard to read @tobias_k